# Error in Git- fatal: '/Users/username/Downloads/folder_name' is outside repository

Tags: git

When I am adding a new project to git, I am getting this error.

```
Error - fatal: '/Users/username/Downloads/folder_name' is outside repository
```

How to get ride of this error? I think, I need to give the current working directory. But, don't know how to do that..Can anyone help me out of this? 
But when I add new file directly, it works fine..
Your help is highly appreciated..Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exact command you issue to "add a new project to Git"? I'm asking because Git has no concept of "projects" -- it operates on repositories.  So a typical way to add "a project" (in the sense of a single directory full or files and/or subdirectories) is to `cd` to its root, run `git init` *in it* then possibly create a suitable `.gitignore` file to ignore junk files (those like `*.obj`) and then `git add .` followed by `git commit`.  So... what are *you* doing? Please be as much specific as possible.

Comment: This is the command I am using when adding new folder to git in my mac...       git add /Users/dineshkumar/Documents/sampleios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git is not able to track files outside of the repository, and so when you're doing

```
git add /Users/dineshkumar/Documents/sampleios
```

Git tells you just that, literally: the path you're trying to add lies outside of the initialized repository you're in.

The term repository is a bit moot so let's make it more clear.

Usually you work with Git like this:

```
$ mkdir project; cd project
$ git init
$ vim upload.php
...
$ git add upload.php
...
$ git commit
```

When you run `git init` in a directory ("project" in our case) Git creates a special subdirectory named ".git" in it — which contains the actual repository data (objects and configuration) — and then turns the enclosing directory into *a work tree.*  The work tree contains the files which you actually edit and submit to Git to build up the next commit.

The crucial propety of this design is that only files located in the work tree are managed by Git.  You can't `git add` a file from somewhere else — only from within the work tree.  Consequently, no one calls `git add` with full paths because this has no sense.

I'm not sure where your confusion is rooted.  If you think that the `git add` command is supposed to *copy* a file/directory from somewhere into the work tree, you're wrong.  If you were't aware of the work tree and thought that the repository is able to track arbitrary files on a filesystem tree, you're wrong again — how would cloning work if this was true?

You should make yourself familiar with the idea that `git add` is not for *adding files* to the repository, it's rather for *adding changes* in files into the so-called staging area, from which the next commit is made.  Adding a presently untracked file is just a special case of this — this addition is just a whole-file "change".

Looking at your attempts I might make a guess that you want to turn `/Users/dineshkumar/Documents/sampleios` into a Git repository.  If this is the case, do

```
$ cd /Users/dineshkumar/Documents/sampleios
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit
```

But before you do that *please* start with [the book](http://git-scm.com/book) as you seem to lack the most basic Git knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think the root of the problem lies in using tools like CVS or SourceSafe where working directory is saved stored as a shadow folder somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

assuming your directory `/Users/username/Downloads/folder_name/` is within a git-repository (e.g. you are tracking `/Users/username/Downloads/`), simply do:

```
cd /Users/username/Downloads/
git add folder_name/
git commit
```

NOTE: i would not recommend tracking the `Downloads/` folder, as this is volatile by nature.
instead it might make more sense to track `Projects/`

a git workbench repository is a directory that contains a `.git` folder. to add anything to the repository, it has to be within a repository (that is: in a subdirectory of the repository): *you cannot track a folder/file that is outside of a git-repository*.