# Why am I getting fatal: file is outside repository from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am trying to push a file on Git within a Jenkins job:

IN JENKINS I added a Windows shell command job and this is the first command:

```
git add "C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\HW\index.html"
```

But I got the following error:

```
fatal: C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\HW\index.html: 'C:\Users\AMRABET\Documents\VSC\HW\index.html' is outside repository
```

Same command works from Windows CMD. It works well from windows. My question is different because I only get it in Jenkins

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Git- fatal: '/Users/username/Downloads/folder\_name' is outside repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908216/error-in-git-fatal-users-username-downloads-folder-name-is-outside-reposito)

Comment: Nope. I just edited and precised (again, because i already did before) that my error comes when i execute thecommand within jenkins

Comment: Well, is your repository in that HW folder, or one of its parent folders? VSC? Documents? etc.?

Comment: You need to copy the file into your working folder first, then add it.

Comment: Perhaps your question, then, is why the Jenkins repository does not match the Git repository. That is a Jenkins question, not a Git-or-GitHub question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I was just out of the git repo.

Actually when in Jenkins you do

```
cd C:\Location
AnotherShellAction
git add RandomFile
```

the git action will be executed not from C:\Location you mentionned but from the default workspace.
It means that you need to enter the wanted Location again after every instruction. Good way would then be:

```
cd C:\Location
AnotherShellAction
cd C:\Location
git add RandomFile
```